# android and jsoup trouble

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to use JSoup in my android app to parse a certain website. However I don't seem to be getting anywhere. I've added the .jar of jsoup to the class path and tried to follow the examples on the JSoup website resource, the cookbook.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.jsoup_layout );

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect( "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" ).get();
        Elements pTag = doc.select( "p" );

        String pTagString = pTag.html();
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), pTagString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), myString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );

}
```

So from this I'm trying to get the p tags of the wikipedia website. There are 12 or so in total but I only really want to display the value of one at this stage. But my app won't do anything. Even the first toast message meant to just display a message doesn't appear - this was only a check to see if it was working. So does anyone know what the problem is? Am i following the current syntax by choosing:

```
Elements pTag = doc.select( "p" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should not connect to a website on the main thread!** Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for such an operation.

Also, to display a Toast, you need to call `show()`:

```
Toast
    .makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
```

Comment: Thanks it works now - still can't believe I didn't spot the .show() method lack of call. Cheers mate :D